# How to use stop() properly in jQuery animation with hover event?

Tags: jquery, animation, hover

I use the method below to make some animation. But when I move my mouse in and out really fast and stop it inside the `div` , the `fadeIn()` doesn't work and the  `div` keeps transparent.

```
$(".grids").hover(function() {
    $('.gridscontrol').stop().fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $('.gridscontrol').stop().fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) without parameters simply stops the animation, still leaving it in queue.  In this case you want `.stop(true)` to clear the animation queue as well.

```
$(".grids").hover(function() {
  $('.gridscontrol').stop(true).fadeTo(200, 1);
}, function() {
  $('.gridscontrol').stop(true).fadeTo(200, 0);
});
```

Also note the use of [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) since `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` shortcuts have some undesirable behavior here.  [You can see a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JbwR3/3/).

Comment: It still doesn't work. If I move my mouse back into the `div` during the `fadeOut()` animation, It just stop and doesn't trigger the `fadeIn()` animation.

Comment: @chbdetta - the fade shortcuts have some undesirable effects in the latest versions of jQuery, check out the updated answer with `.fadeTo()` instead.

Comment: hi @NickCraver can please solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178170/settimeout-not-working-with-custom-jquery-plugin

Comment: @NickCraver Sorry if ask for your help here, but I really need a hand here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403503/jquery-how-to-split-table-cell-into-a-different-number-of-rows-from-column-to-co  Again, I do apologize for commenting on someone else's question

Answer (score 2):

[.stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Set both `clearQueue` and `jumpToEnd` to `true`.

```
$(".grids").hover(function() {
    $('.gridscontrol').stop(true, true).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $('.gridscontrol').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: The second argument to `.stop()` tells it to jump to the end of the queue, you wouldn't really want that in a hover case, since that would trigger a 100% opacity blink then fade out in the leaving case for example.